# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined: React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql

I'm working on fetching data with React and graphql and render it with react/pdf-renderer.

I use renderContent but it gives me this error. What I'm doing wrong?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bookingConfirmationNumber')at renderContent

Below is my code

```
const renderContent = () => {
    const hotelDetails: HotelDetailsType = data.getHotelDetailsByIds.items[0]

    return (
      <PDFViewer>
        <Document>
          console.log(hotelDetails.bookingConfirmationNumber)
          <Page>

            <View>
                <Text>{hotelDetails.bookingConfirmationNumber}</Text>
                <Text>{hotelDetails.hotelName}</Text>
                <Text>{hotelDetails.address}</Text>
                <Text>{hotelDetails.hotelContactNumber}</Text>
                <Text>{hotelDetails.guestName}</Text>
                <Text>{hotelDetails.guests.adults}</Text>
                <Text>{hotelDetails.guests.children}</Text>
            </View>
          </Page>
        </Document>
      </PDFViewer>      
  )}
```

Here is my schema

```
export type HotelDetailsType = {
  bookingConfirmationNumber: string
  hotelName: string
  address: string
  hotelContactNumber: string
  guestName: string
  guests: HotelGuestsType
}
```

I tried optional chaining, it renders the PDF component but data were not being fetched and Query is working fine in Graphql. Any inputs and resource to read on is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Update:

`hotelDetails` is indeed sending undefined. But I still can't figure out why. If I query directly in graphql it is working. Please see below additional info.

```
const InvoicePDFModal: React.FC<InvoicePDFModalProps> = ({ hideModal, hotelBookingId }) => {
  const profile = useSelector(selectedCustomerProfileSelector)
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_HOTEL_DETAILS_BY_IDS, {
    variables: {
      hotelDetailIds: [hotelBookingId],
      customerId: profile.userId
    }
  })
```

Graphql snip
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im9z0.jpg

I really appreciate the help guys. Thank you so much.

Comment: hotelDetails look undefined. What is the content of data variable ?

Comment: What is the output of `data.getHotelDetailsByIds`?

Comment: Since you changed the definition of `hotelDetails` in your question, it's tough to understand what you're asking. You need to take a closer look at `data` because you're not getting back what you think you are.

Comment: Hi guys, Thank you for your inputs. and Yes, data is indeed undefined at the moment. I'll check on it again. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

`hotelDetails` is resulting in undefined simply because `data.getHotelDetailsByIds.items[0]` (and `data.getHotelDetailsByIds` in the previous version of your question) is undefined. When you inspect `data`, you should see the issue.

Comment: Hello @abgregs, Apologies for deleting it abruptly, I deleted it to show my original code, I'm checking on my data now. thank you.

Comment: No problem, it happens :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `data.getHotelDetailsByIds` returns empty array. So, `data.getHotelDetailsByIds.item[0]` is `undefined`.